# Finding coefficients in polynomial function

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

Let's say that I have a function $f(x)=6x^3-5x^2-12x+k$. What should I put in *Mathematica* to solve the value of $k$ such that $3x+2$ is a factor of $f(x)$?

Comment: Straightforward maniac computation: `Table[{k, Factor[6 x^3 - 5 x^2 - 12 x + k]}, {k, -6, 6}] // Column` shows `k==-4`.  More finely: `f[x_, k_] := 6 x^3 - 5 x^2 - 12 x + k;  Solve[f[-(2/3), k] == 0, k] `

Answer (score 11):

One liner:

```
Solve[PolynomialRemainder[6 x^3 - 5 x^2 - 12 x + k, 3 x + 2, x] == 0, k]
```

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice the flip. Thanks @Runny!

Comment: you're welcome.

Comment: @RunnyKine I observe that you have largely stopped posting here.  Is everything OK?  I hope that you find the time and interest to participate more actively as you once did.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Thanks for the concern. I hope to start participating actively again soon. Just not in the right state of mind currently. Thanks again.

Comment: @RunnyKine I am glad you are well and I completely understand needing to be in the right mood for it.  Should you move on to other things let me say thanks for all your contributions; I have some sense of the time involved in that.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_] := 6 x^3 - 5 x^2 - 12 x
poly = f[x] - f[-2/3]
```

so

```
PolynomialRemainder[poly, 3 x + 2, x]
```

yields 0